# How to extract links from markdown

Tags: regex, go, hyperlink, markdown

I'm trying to parse an input that may either be a hyperlink or a hyperlink in markdown. I can easily check whether it's a hyperlink with `^https?://.+$` and use regexp.Match, but with markdown links it's a whole different rabbit hole for me.

I came across this regex `^\[([\w\s\d]+)\]\((https?:\/\/[\w\d./?=#]+)\)$` which I tried to modify to match *only* the markdown link but after having the last parantheses captured for some reason, I've just been looking at just matching the 2nd capture group, the link, with things like SubexpNames, FindStringIndex, FindSubmatch, Split and so on, but none of them seem to either capture what I'm looking for (sometimes they return the entire string anyway) or most likely I'm doing it wrong.

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
Input - [https://imgur.com/abc](https://imgur.com/bcd)
Should output the link - https://imgur.com/bcd
```

Here's my code so far: https://play.golang.org/p/OiJE3TvvVb6

Comment: Why do you need a regex at all? Just check if the first character is `[`.

Comment: Just to check if it's a valid http link, and then preferably I'd just like to parse the link itself from the markdown link

Comment: What kind of parsing are you doing?

Comment: Basically I'm taking the input, which may be a hyperlink or a markdown link, then I'm embedding the link somewhere else with ReplaceAll on another string. ```
toEdit = `*[THE LINK TO THE TEMPLATE](%LINK%)*`
toEdit = strings.ReplaceAll(toEdit, "%LINK%", link)
```

Comment: So you're not parsing the URL, you're only extracting it?

Comment: Meant to say extracting, yes, sorry

Comment: Do you need to support relative URLs?  i.e. `[Foo](/some/path)`?

Comment: Nope, only looking for http/https URLs

Comment: And do you have the URLs in isolation, or they're embedded in larger text? i.e. is your input literally `[Foo](https://example.com)`, or is it a full document like `Go to [Foo](https://example.com) for a good time`?

Comment: The URLs are only in isolation, this is more of a command sort of thing

Comment: In that case, just extract everything between the parenthesis. A regex is probably not the best tool, because it's fairly inefficient, but it should work. Something like `\((.*)\)` should do it.

Comment: I think that'll do it, thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that can break if you have parenthesis in your descriptions.  I.e. `[Foo (bar)](http://example.com/)` would break. This is one reason a regular expression is the wrong tool for a job like this. The best solution would be to use a proper Markdown parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `regexp.FindStringSubmatch` to get the captured value yielded by your single-URL validating regex:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    markdownRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`^\[[^][]+]\((https?://[^()]+)\)$`)
    results := markdownRegex.FindStringSubmatch("[https://imgur.com/abc](https://imgur.com/bcd)")
    fmt.Printf("%q", results[1])
}
```

See the [GO demo online](https://play.golang.org/p/93wBk6HkyM9).

You may consider using `regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch` to find all occurrences of the links you need:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    markdownRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`\[[^][]+]\((https?://[^()]+)\)`)
    results := markdownRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch("[https://imgur.com/abc](https://imgur.com/bcd) and [https://imgur.com/xyy](https://imgur.com/xyz)", -1)
    for v := range results {fmt.Printf("%q\n", results[v][1])}
}
```

See the [Go lang demo](https://play.golang.org/p/qCx5eBvtwld)

The pattern means:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]+` - 1+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\(` -  `](` substring
- `(https?://[^()]+)`  - Group 1: `http`, then an optional `s`, then a  `://` substring, and then 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CBeLD/1).